# Add text and remove text in Google Docs (Add-on)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-api

We have an Add-on for Doc's where it inserts data to the document, we would also like it to remove the text when you click the button **again**, like a switch. As it is right now, at a press on the button the second time, third time and so on.. it populates new text over the already existing.

[image]

**Client-Side:**

```
<div class="block" id="button-bar">
          <button onclick="google.script.run.insertTextA();" id="TextA">Text A</button>
          <button onclick="google.script.run.insertTextB();" id="TextB">Text B</button>   
          </div>
```

**Server-Side:**

```
function insertTextA() {
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var text = body.editAsText();
 text.insertText(11, 'There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..');                         
}

function insertTextB() {
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var text = body.editAsText();
 text.insertText(12, 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old..');
}
```

Comment: what is your attempt at removing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function insertTextA() {
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var val = body.findText('There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..');
  if(val == null)
  {
   var text = body.editAsText();
   text.insertText(11, 'There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..');         
  }
  else
  {
    body.replaceText('There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..','');
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks iJay for pointing me in the right direction, ofc an if-statement with replaceText will work, why didn't i think of it my self :]